# как подтянуть сторонние модули python в exe

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

собрать свои самописные модули в один `exe` с помощью `pyinstaller` вышло, но можно ли каким то образом также и сторонние модули подтянуть в `exe` и не таскать их в виртуальном окружении рядом с исполняемым файлом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо вызвать `pyinstaller` с опцией `--onefile` в самом виртуальном окружении, а не вне его.